# Missing iTunes store app on iPhone

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

The ITunes store app has gone from my phone. When i go to app store, the option open doesn't work.

Also it's not in icloud.

Comment: Which app is missing, the iTunes app or the App Store app?

Comment: The Itunes store app

Comment: Ok. Can you add a screenshot of the App Store showing the iTunes store app (or whatever you are referring to in the second sentence)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings > General > Restrictions and confirm that restrictions are off. If restrictions are on, you'll need the restrictions passcode to turn it off.

Also, confirm that the top of settings doesn't have text mentioning "This phone is supervised and managed by..." at the top. If it does, talk to your company's IT specialist for more detail.

Lastly, on the home screen, pull down in the middle of the screen to reveal the search menu. Type "app store" and confirm that it doesn't show up there. If it does, it's likely in a folder or you simply missed it.

Comment: @LAURA Out of curiosity, which answer of mine solved your question?